# How can I use the google app script to get values from one column based on a condition I set on another column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

say for example i have my table that looks like this [sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOJz3.png)

| MED TIMING | PHONE |
| --- | --- |
| Breakfast | 1 |
| Lunch | 2 |
| Lunch | 3 |
| Breakfast | 4 |
| Dinner | 5 |

Now how do I store values of the phone column corresponding to the row which has value "Breakfast" in a variable in app script, i.e. I want to put a condition that if 'MED TIMING' = "Breakfast", I want to store the values [1,4] in a variable. 
In the image above, there is a screenshot of the sheet so that someone could explain how to set the condition with the column number as well

Could anyone please help me out? Hope my question is understadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [an array filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) to get a new array with only the condition you want.

```
function getFiltered(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var theValues = ss.getRange("a:B").getValues();
  var breakfastValues = theValues.filter(x => x[0]=="Breakfast");

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer! I was having problems on how to display my var BreakfastValues and was wondering if you could help by telling me how i can display it on the execution log? i tried everything but couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: Use the debug tool and put a breakpoint in the code and look to the right. Faster than using consol.log. I should make a video on this as it's not very well documented....

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to @pgSystemTester's answer that uses a for loop.

```
function getFiltered() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var theValues = ws.getRange("a:b").getValues();
  
 //Removes the header row
  theValues = theValues.slice(1)
  var breakfastValues = []

  for (let i = 0; i < theValues.length; i++) {
    if (theValues[i][0] === "Breakfast") {
       breakfastValues.push(theValues[i][1]);
    }
  }
 return breakfastValues
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).